# I'm trying to make a simple line drawing program with tkinter but it won't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make this really simple program, all it does is store the current `x/y` pos of the mouse on the canvas and then use them to *draw a line* when you click for the second time. I've already bound it and I'm not getting any errors, it seems like it's not even being **activated**. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
from tkinter import *
main = Tk()
c = Canvas(main, width=600, height=600)
c.pack()
#For colored lines
presses = 0
def click(event):
    if presses == 0:
        initX = int(c.canvasx(event.x))
        initY = int(c.canvasy(event.y))
        presses == 1
    elif presses == 1:
        c.create_line(initX, initY,
        int(c.canvasx(event.x)),
        int(c.canvasy(event.y)))
        presses == 0




c.bind("<Button-1>", click)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does something like this work for you?

```
from tkinter import *
main = Tk()
c = Canvas(main, width=600, height=600)
c.pack()
line = []

def click(event):
    global line
    X = int(c.canvasx(event.x))
    Y = int(c.canvasy(event.y))
    line.append((X,Y))
    if len(line) > 1:
        startX,startY = line[-2]
        c.create_line(startX, startY, X, Y)

c.bind("<Button-1>", click)
mainloop()
```

I've changed around your code a bit to store a list of the X,Y coordinates that have been clicked on. If more than 1 point on the screen has been clicked, it will draw a line between the current point clicked on and the last point clicked on.

Reason your code wasn't working was that initX and initY are forgotten in between calls on the the click function. Adding them to a list solves this.